# Finding minimum value of bloom filter function

Tags: maxima-minima

Bloom filter definition from Wikipedia:

> A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure,
>   conceived by Burton Howard Bloom in 1970, that is used to test whether
>   an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible,
>   but false negatives are not – in other words, a query returns either
>   "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set". Elements can be added to
>   the set, but not removed (though this can be addressed with a
>   "counting" filter); the more elements that are added to the set, the
>   larger the probability of false positives.

If `m` is the number of bits in the array, `k` is the number of hash functions and we have `n` entries, then the false positive probability upper bound can be approximated as:

$$ (1 - e^\frac{-kn}{m})^k $$

It further states in the wiki article that:

> The number of hash functions, k, must be a positive integer. Putting
>   this constraint aside, for a given m and n, the value of k that
>   minimizes the false positive probability is:

$$ k={\frac {m}{n}}\ln 2 $$

How can I find the `k` value that minimizes the false positive function ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that that is correct.
Perhaps one of the
$k$'s is wrong.

Anyway,
here's my take.

Let
$f(k)
=(1 - e^\frac{-kn}{m})^k
=(1 - e^{ak})^k
$
where
$a = -n/m$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f'(k)
&=((1 - e^{ak})^k)'\\
&=(e^{k\ln(1 - e^{ak})})'\\
&=(k\ln(1 - e^{ak}))'(e^{k\ln(1 - e^{ak})})
\qquad\text{since } (e^{g(k)})' = g'(k)e^{g(k)}\\
&=(\ln(1 - e^{ak})+k(\ln(1 - e^{ak}))')(e^{k\ln(1 - e^{ak})})\\
&=(\ln(1 - e^{ak})+k\dfrac{(1 - e^{ak})'}{1 - e^{ak}})(1 - e^{ak})^k
\qquad\text{since } (\ln(g))' = \dfrac{g'}{g}\\
&=(\ln(1 - e^{ak})+k\dfrac{- ae^{ak}}{1 - e^{ak}})(1 - e^{ak})^k\\
&=\dfrac{\ln(1 - e^{ak})(1 - e^{ak})- kae^{ak}}{1 - e^{ak}}(1 - e^{ak})^k\\
&=0
\qquad\text{when }(1 - e^{ak})\ln(1 - e^{ak})=kae^{ak}\\
\end{array}
$

Let
$1-e^{ak} = y$,
so
$k = \ln(1-y)/a
$.

Then
$(1 - e^{ak})\ln(1 - e^{ak})=kae^{ak}
$
becomes
$y\ln(y)=(\ln(1-y)/a)(1-y)
$
or
$y^y
=(1-y)^{(1-y)/a}
$.

I don't see how to solve this.